# C# & ASP.NET MVC roles - rolling back deleted roles when passing through context and not commiting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-roles

This is the simplified partial pseudo code from the calling method:

```
using (var context = new ModelContext())
{
    var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        // Delete stuff here
        Users.DeleteAllByClient(context, clientToDelete.ClientId);
        
        // And delete stuff here
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        
        return;
    }
}
```

Take the example method, used to delete user details and their profile.

The `ModelContext context` is passed through to the method, which means that if the calling method does not commit `transaction.Commit();` causing a rollback, this will not occur for the roles. They will have already been deleted.

Is it possible to add the `Roles.RemoveUserFromRoles(item.User.UserName, roles);` to the rollback?

I can't use `TransactionScope` (nested or not) as opposed to passing the context through.

```
public static void DeleteAllByClient(ModelContext context, int clientId)
{
    // Users to delete
    var models = context.UserDetails.Where(o => o.ClientId == clientId).ToList();

    // list of user profiles
    List<UserProfile> userProfileList = new List<UserProfile>();

    foreach (var item in models)
    {
        var userProfile = context.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(o => o.UserId == item.UserId);
        var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(userProfile.UserName); 

        // these need to roll back if commit doesn't happen
        Roles.RemoveUserFromRoles(item.User.UserName, roles); 

        userProfileList.Add(userProfile);
    }

    if (models.Count > 0)
    {
        context.UserDetails.BulkDelete(models); // db tables specified for clarity
        context.UserProfiles.BulkDelete(userProfileList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be easy enough to write your own `Roles.RemoveUserFromRoles(item.User.UserName, roles);`  that uses the same context/transaction.

Comment: Thank you but the specific Roles table is not exposed as it is handled by system classes such as Roles